# How do I enlarge LatLngBounds box using LatLng data

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I get the current bounds of a google map by calling:

```
map.getBounds()
```

This will return LatLngBounds. For example:

```
((-26.574013562724005, -1.5375947819336488), (-25.230016040794602, 3.735842718066351))
```

Is it possible to get the the new LatLng points if I want to increase the map bounds by a percentage (e.g. 1%) around the centre of the map.

I have tried multiplying every coordinate by 1.01 but this shifts the map and does not increase the bounds.

I want to use the increased box size to start caching markers, in order to save calls to the server when the user pans or zooms out.

The image below will explain better what needs to happen:

[image]

Comment: Simplest option is to decrease the zoom level by one (`map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1)`), unless you are only trying to draw a box that represents those bounds on the map.

Comment: I dont want to decrease the zoom level, I want to start loading markers outside of the current bounds for caching.

Comment: Please clarify that in your question.

Comment: 100% I have added it.

Comment: Your picture is not what you are saying.  You want the bounds increased by a percentage, that would make the y direction increase a smaller amount than the x direction, which is not what your picture shows.  Do you want to increase the bounds by a constant pixel amount (not geographic distance)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [markerclusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js) `getExtendedBounds` function you could use this one:

```
function getExtendedBounds(map, overlay) {
    //With _mapBoundsEnlargePixels we add some extra space surrounding the map
    //change this value until you get the desired size
    var _mapBoundsEnlargePixels = 500;

    var projection = overlay.getProjection();
    var bounds = angular.copy(map.getBounds());

    // Turn the bounds into latlng.
    var tr = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
        bounds.getNorthEast().lng());
    var bl = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
        bounds.getSouthWest().lng());

    // Convert the points to pixels and extend out
    var trPix = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(tr);
    trPix.x = trPix.x + _mapBoundsEnlargePixels;
    trPix.y = trPix.y - _mapBoundsEnlargePixels;

    var blPix = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(bl);
    blPix.x = blPix.x - _mapBoundsEnlargePixels;
    blPix.y = blPix.y + _mapBoundsEnlargePixels;

    // Convert the pixel points back to LatLng
    var ne = projection.fromDivPixelToLatLng(trPix);
    var sw = projection.fromDivPixelToLatLng(blPix);

    // Extend the bounds to contain the new bounds.
    bounds.extend(ne);
    bounds.extend(sw);

    return bounds;
}
```

Comment: I ended up taking a total different approach but this answer was still useful. Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you shared your approach.

Comment: yes, would be interested in your approach aswell, @Morne