# google map v3 bounds_changed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);

    var searched = document.getElementById("pac-input").value;

    var radarRequest = {
        bounds: bounds,
        keyword: searched
    };
    serviceRadar.radarSearch(radarRequest, callback);

});
```

Given the above code:
Whenever bounds changes (map), I do a new radar search. Is there a way to set it so that bounds_change (user drag over 75% of the current bound change), then it'll pull up a new radar search?

Let me know if that make any sense... I know you can do addListener with drag drop, but what about its condition on the detecting % of dragged from the current bound change?

If its not achievable... any suggestion on tackling this issue?

Comment: the 75% change could be interpreted in many ways, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704994/how-do-i-enlarge-latlngbounds-box-using-latlng-data/28705156) where the user wanted todo something similar (if my interpretation of that 75% change is correct of course)

Comment: @FelipePereira That gives me some idea, but it is a bit different. Sounded like he wanted to preload outside the given bound... but I cannot do that due to the fact that radar search gives 200 points. If I set center of the current map view.. I wonder how exactly to tell what distance dragged (hitting the edge of inner window) and load a new set of radar search. Need to take into account that dragging back to center is not an issue.

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly, will this work?: you have mapR that is what the user sees, and map75 that is mapR+75%, initially you do a radar search with map75 bounds and load that data, when user drags mapR out of map75 (you can compare both maps bounds) you perform another search

Comment: From where you are referring serviceRadar.radarSearch(radarRequest, callback); data. This method is not specified in Google API...

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this, But first I would recommend you to take a look at the [Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical). Here is what you can do.

- First calculate the Horizontal and Vertical dimensions of the existing bound.
- Then multiply both of them by .75 which will give you the 75% of the actual bound.
- Add that obtained value to the actual bound which will be the 75% increased bound of the actual one.
- Keep checking using a conditional if.. else, that when this condition is met execute the radarSearch() function.

I am sure writing code for this would be pretty easy.

Hope that Helps!!