# Flutter Map - Enlarge LatLngBounds by a certains percent/pixel

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

I have a map with some clusters, but the clusters are cut when I'm using LatLngBounds to center the map. I need to add a padding to ensure that all the clusters are visible.
I try using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704994/how-do-i-enlarge-latlngbounds-box-using-latlng-data/28705156#28705156). It's sometimes working, but not when the zoom is high and I don't understand why (in this case, the padding is really to large).
I'm using [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) package.

Here what I have done (the mapBoundsEnlargePixels is random for now, i try to find the right value):

```dart
    _latLngBounds = LatLngBounds.fromPoints(markers.map((e) => e.point).toList());
    final mapBoundsEnlargePixels = 24;

    const Crs crs = Epsg4326();
    final CustomPoint<double> northEast =
        crs.latLngToPoint(bounds.northEast, _mapController.zoom);
    final CustomPoint<double> southWest =
        crs.latLngToPoint(bounds.southWest, _mapController.zoom);

    // north east
    final northEastX = northEast.x + mapBoundsEnlargePixels;
    final northEastY = northEast.y - mapBoundsEnlargePixels;
   
    // south west
    final southWestX = southWest.x - mapBoundsEnlargePixels;
    final southWestY = southWest.y + mapBoundsEnlargePixels; 

    final LatLng? ne = crs.pointToLatLng(CustomPoint(northEastX, northEastY), _mapController.zoom);
    final LatLng? sw = crs.pointToLatLng(CustomPoint(southWestX, southWestY), _mapController.zoom);

    if (ne != null && sw != null) {
      _latLngBounds!.extendBounds(LatLngBounds(ne, sw));
      // Make small move on the map to fix tile not loaded when center to Bounds
      print(_mapController.zoom);
      _mapController
        ..fitBounds(bounds)
        ..move(_mapController.center, _mapController.zoom + 0.000001);
    }
```

If you have an explanation, or even an other method that could be used, that'll be useful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version of [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) package allow you to set padding after setting bounds of map.

```
_mapController.fitCamera(CameraFit.bounds(bounds: bounds),padding: EdgeInsets.all(10));
```

you don't need to calculate zoom level.

Comment: That's right, I wasn't on the lastest version.
I works fine, thanks a lot !